# Mysql ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY + Join + GroupBy + Count = invalid count

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, left-join

I'm trying to run query like:

```
SELECT cc.slug AS cc_slug
     , cp.slug AS cp_slug
     , COUNT(cp.id) 
  FROM catalog_categories AS cc 
  LEFT 
  JOIN catalog_products cp 
    ON cc.id = cp.category_id 
 GROUP 
    BY cc.id
     , cp.id
```

And expecting to get number of associated products for each category, but I'm retrieving only '0' and '1' instead of correct count. It caused by the second grouping `group by ... cp.id` but it can not be removed as ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is enabled. So for example if I run query like (without grouping by joined table):

```
SELECT COUNT(cp.id) 
  FROM catalog_categories AS cc 
  LEFT 
  JOIN catalog_products cp 
    ON cc.id = cp.category_id 
 GROUP 
    BY cc.id
```

I'm getting correct results, but the problem is that I need all these fields and aliases in SELECT.

Is there any way to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place the `cp.id` in an aggregate function like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(cp.id), MAX(cp.id) 
FROM catalog_categories AS cc 
LEFT JOIN catalog_products cp ON cc.id = cp.category_id 
GROUP BY cc.id
```

This way you can pick the maximum `cp.id` per `cc.id`.

Comment: Giorgos, it works, but in my case my query is generated automatically and I have cp.id aliased as something like 'cp_id' and mysql ignores 'cp.id' aggregated and continue ti produce errors.

Comment: @pandomic Then use `MAX(cp_id)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT cc.slug AS cc_slug, cp.slug AS cp_slug, COUNT(cp.id)
FROM catalog_categories cc LEFT JOIN
     catalog_products cp
     ON cc.id = cp.category_id
GROUP BY cc.slug, cp.slug;
```

The *non-aggregated* columns should be in the `GROUP BY`.

EDIT:

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT cc.slug AS cc_slug, COUNT(cp.id)
FROM catalog_categories cc LEFT JOIN
     catalog_products cp
     ON cc.id = cp.category_id
GROUP BY cc.slug;
```

Comment: Gordon, I normally refrain from editing your answers. But I don't think you meant to include the `AS cc_slug` in the `GROUP BY` clause. +10. We include all of the non-aggregated expressions in the GROUP BY clause. (Some databases will let us slide by omitting some expressions (e.g. literals) when the optimizer can determine there's a functional dependency.

Comment: I'm still getting 1/0 results instead of the real count